Need replacement for a discontinued Porcher faucet
Our Porcher Reprise Bridge faucet broke off today:

Unfortunately, the model's been discontinued years ago and no one seems to have it in stock.
But the schematic shows, the top part can be unscrewed from the base -- above the part A912613-0070A.
Perhaps, I can find a suitable replacement? Either from a newer model -- or, maybe, even from a different manufacturer?
Any suggestions?

Generally speaking, faucets in the US are based on a 4" distance between the hot and cold for bathrooms and 8" for kitchens. There are some exceptions designed for a single hole or for 3 separate individually mounted sections (hot, cold, output; plus a 4th for a kitchen sprayer when included).
Don't try to match the exact faucet - you'll go crazy trying to do that. Just find something that matches the required dimensions, covers any extra holes or other damage ("deck plate" size/shape varies considerably and sometimes they can be replaced separately) and fits your preferred finish (black, white, brass, chrome, etc.) and style.
